# FFmpeg/C/C++: where is located and how decode Closed Caption(608) in Matrox DVCPRO SD files using ffmpeg and c/c++?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm a lit bit crazy with some especific video files. I want to decode them using ffmpeg/c++, specifically decode 608 Closed Captions. The AVI file format/codec is DVCPRO at SD(720x480) resolution. The enconder is "Matrox DSX AVI file . Format: 6. Build: 1.0.0.451" That's was ok, until moment i tried to see or decode 608 closed captions. There was nothing at line 21. So, i decid to play this file in Matrox Sample Video Player(an example of their SDK) and for my surprise there was 608 closed captions. So, i read Matrox SDK documentation, and found this

```
Using closed caption information
Some of the Matrox NTSC codecs can extract the closed caption information from the
video buffers and store it as metadata in the compressed buffer. On decompression,
these same codecs can restore the lines to their proper position. Other NTSC codecs
just encode the closed caption lines as video data. The closed caption lines that are
extracted are defined by the EIA-608 specification. The two lines are defined as lines
21 from both the first and second fields.
The following codecs keep the closed caption lines as metadata (NTSC only):
• Matrox DV (encode and decode).
• Matrox MPEG-2 I-frame (encode and decode).
• Matrox MPEG-2 IBP, except 720×512 resolution (decode only).
The following codecs keep the closed caption lines as video data (NTSC only):
• Matrox D10 (encode and decode).
• Matrox MPEG-2 IBP in 720 ×512 resolution (decode only).
• Matrox M-JPEG (decode only).
```

So, i thought that VBI or Closed Caption(608) will be stored at some metadata. But, exploring the entire file using **ffmpeg/libavcodec with C/C++**, i found nothing "hide" in metadata. Even in frames metadata. Is like magic. There is nothing in line 21 and nothing in metadata's. So, how Matrox sample example is the only one video player that show's it?

Comment: I'm stiil on same problem. I wrote a small AVI parser using c++ to verify this AVI content. All chunks seems to be right and there's no data stream and no subtitle stream neither. So, from where this closed caption 608 come from? it seems that isn't anywhere, but when i play it using Matrox Video Player ... this 608 closed caption show's ok. With all others players, including ffmpeg, it dosent show it.

Comment: There is something very interesting in this case. The MAtrox Sample Player "Flex Channel Tester" treats
this video as 720x486 instead 720x480. And this, makes all sense, cause in digital video, the analog line
21, needs a few more lines, what leaves as 486 instead 480 pixels.

So, i know maybe i am being stuped asking what i will ask you guys now...

but, if try force(changing sourcecode of course) ffmpeg treat this video stream as 720x486, forcing decoder uses additional bytes maybe can
work to bring back full video displayiung the CC608 on top?

Yeah.. i know it sounds stupped